# What is a good way of looping through lines in a multi-line string?

Tags: c, string, parsing

My function `foo(char *str)` receives `str` that is a multiline string with new line characters that is null-terminated. I am trying to write a while loop that iterates through the string and operates on one line. What is a good way of achieving this?

```
void foo(char *str) {
    while((line=getLine(str)) != NULL) {
        // Process a line
    }
}
```

Do I need to implement `getLine` myself or is there an in-built function to do this for me?

Comment: There is a built-in `getline`, but it's not what you want.  It's for getting a line at a time from a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement some kind of parsing based on the new line character yourself. strtok() with a delimiter of "\n" is a pretty good option that does something like what you're looking for but it has to be used slightly differently than your example. It would be more like:

```
char *tok;
char *delims = "\n";
tok = strtok(str, delims);

while (tok != NULL) {
  // process the line

  //advance the token
  tok = strtok(NULL, delims);
}
```

You should note, however, that strtok() is both destructive and not threadsafe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might use `strtok`, which tokenizes a string into packets delimited by some specific characters, in your case the newline character:

```
void foo(char *str)
{
    char *line = strtok(str, "\n");
    while(line)
    {
        //work with line, which contains a single line without the trailing '\n'
        ...

        //next line
        line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that this alters the contents of `str` (it actually replaces the `'\n'`s by `'\0'`s), so you may want to make a copy of it beforehand if you need it further.

Answer (score 1):

Sooo... a bit late, but below is a re-entrant version of @debeer's and @Christian Rau's answer - notice `strtok_r` instead of `strtok`.
This can be called from multiple threads using different strings.

```
char *tok;
char *saveptr;
char *delims = "\n";
tok = strtok_r(str, delims, &saveptr);

while (tok != NULL) {
  // process the line

  //advance the token
  tok = strtok_r(NULL, delims, &saveptr);
}
```

Please note that it is still destructive as it modifies the string being tokenised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets` to do the `getLine` work: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: He wants to read lines from a string rather than a file. I'm not sure if C has string streams.

Comment: @ChristianRau C doesn't have `stringstream`s, but it does have `fgets`, which doesn't use them.  But, you are right that the OP wanted lines from a string, not a file.

Comment: @Kevin I just thought there might be a way to create a file descriptor for a string, which would be the C-way of a string stream.